# Round off total value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(this).closest('table').find('.total1').val(($(this).closest('table').find('.total').val() * price) / $(this).closest('table').find('.inrvalue').val());
```

How will i round off the total1 value to 3 decimals?

Comment: you will need to use javascript, jquery doesn't have a maths library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Number.toFixed(n)*

This is native JS, no need for a particular JQuery function.

```
var value = 10.123456.toFixed(3);
// value = 10.123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign total1 value into different variable and do like this;

```
   var total1= 4.34597;
   var total1Rounded= Math.round(total1* 1000) / 1000;
```